How to configure proxy settings for google vertex AI python SDK?
I'm trying to configure the Google Cloud Vertex AI Python SDK (https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform) to work behind a corporate proxy in a production environment.
All network connections in my environment are required to route through this proxy.
Is there a way to configure it only for the Google Vertex AI Python SDK without interfering with other parts of my system or applications?
Is there a built-in method or a recommended pattern to achieve per-instance or per-client proxy configuration for the Vertex AI Python SDK?
My current Python code is structured somewhat like this :
import vertexai

# ...
class VertexClient

    def generate_stream(credentials, contents):
        vertexai.init(project="...", location="...", credentials=credentials)
        model = GenerativeModel("...")
        generation_config = GenerationConfig(max_output_tokens=8192, temperature=1, top_p=0.05)
        return model.generate_content(
                contents=contents,
                generation_config=generation_config,
                stream=True)

Setting the proxy globally using environment variables (https_proxy, http_proxy) affects other applications and Kubernetes pods, which causes disruptions and system instability.
I also tried setting and then unsetting environment variables programmatically within my Python code for each generate_stream call:
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "http://my-proxy:port"
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://my-proxy:port"

I'm not entirely certain, but I believe this approach could potentially introduce issues if I set and unset the environment in this manner.
Any help or guidance would be appreciated!

You need to find out which network library(I hope it's one of the popular HTTP client libs) is used to make the calls over the network. Then, it will be clear how to configure it or instrument the code to force it using a proxy.
